# Getting the opposite numbers or getting IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

When the `String layout` is the following:

```
String layout =
      "b....\n"+
      ".....\n"+
      "....b\n"+
      "";
```

then my code reads number of its rows and columns completely wrong. For the row number it shows me column number and vice versa. For the above example, the number of rows is 3 and columns is 5. But Im getting indexOutOfBoundsException when test some examples and/or opposite numbers (instead of rows number it shows columns number, and instead of columns it shows rows number). Could smb take a look at the logic of the code?

```
public static Shape makeShape(String layout,char displayChar)
  {
      Shape passLayout;
      int rows = 0;
      int cols = 0;
      String line = "";
      String firstLine = "";
      String lastLine = "";
      Scanner data = new Scanner(layout);
      firstLine = data.nextLine();

      while(data.hasNextLine())
      {
          line = data.nextLine();
          cols = line.length();
          rows++;
      }
      //line = data.nextLine();
      lastLine = line;
      if((firstLine.charAt(0) == '.' && lastLine.charAt(0) == '.') || 
              (firstLine.charAt(cols) == '.' && lastLine.charAt(cols) == '.'))
          throw new FitItException("OOPS! Empty borders!");
      else 
          passLayout = new CreateShape(rows, cols, displayChar, layout);

      return passLayout;
```

**NOTE: the conditional if-statement checks for the empty chars (`'.'`), i.e. layout strings for shapes must have at least one filled block in each of `0th row`, `0th column`, `last row`, and `last column`.**

Comment: add extra check lastLine.length() > 0 before calling lastLine.charAt(0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where the code would be mixing the values for rows and columns, but I do see a likely cause of your indexOutOfBoundsException. Try changing your if statement:

```
if((firstLine.charAt(0) == '.' && lastLine.charAt(0) == '.') || 
          (firstLine.charAt(cols-1) == '.' && lastLine.charAt(cols-1) == '.'))
      throw new FitItException("OOPS! Empty borders!");
```

The position of the last character will always be one less than the number of columns because of the 0 based index.